# uncaught DOMException after installing and using polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am following this tutorial which teaches the installation of polymer elements:
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/toolbox/add-elements

After running the npm install command and importing it using:

```
import '@polymer/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.js';
```

I am starting to get this error when the page loads:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
```

I had a look around and some say delete node models folder and others say to reinstall web components because there are conflicts between versions but none go into great detail on how this is done.

Comment: I am not completely sure about this because I am using Polymer 2, and this is v3, but I got a very similar error message when I was importing the same component twice with two different relative paths (even if in fact the resolved to the same absolute path)

Comment: mishu is right you try to load the same component twice

Comment: how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: @Taka maybe have a convention on how to include components and go through your files and make sure that all of them follow it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then running `npm install` fixed this. It appears to be due to duplicate dependencies within paper elements.

Comment: this combined with using an admin console fixed the issue, I didnt realize I wasnt giving it perms the previous time I tried this ^_^;